# How to display array of column names between specific index value

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following array of column names, I want to only display the day column names, so 7 - 13

```
array:20 [▼
 0 => "id"
 1 => "customer_id"
 2 => "enrolment_id"
 3 => "course_id"
 4 => "delivery_mode"
 5 => "course_cost"
 6 => "location"
 7 => "Monday"
 8 => "Tuesday"
 9 => "Wednesday"
 10 => "Thursday"
 11 => "Friday"
 12 => "Saturday"
 13 => "Sunday"
 14 => "start_time"
 15 => "end_time"
 16 => "start_date"
 17 => "sale_type"
 18 => "created_at"
 19 => "updated_at"
 ]
```

Array is created in controller with:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('orders');
```

I'm using the following to display the column names as labels for my checkboxes in a blade template view but it shows all column names and not just the days:

```
@foreach($columns as $column)
{{ Form::checkbox($column, 0, null, ['id' => $column,  'class' => 'is-
checkradio is-white']) }}
{{ Form::label($column, $column) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: can you share what you have done in getColumnListing on controller side, I think you over engineered your code

Comment: This is all I have done with getColumnListing: 
    $columns = Schema::getColumnListing('orders');

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jonas

This worked for the question

```
$days = array_slice($columns, 7, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **array_where** from laravel helpers (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-where) to do this job, like this:

```
$columns = array_where($columns, function ($value, $key) {
   return ($value >= 7 && $columns <= 13);
});
```